# Cron expression for Quartz scheduler to fire every 5 minutes from 09:00 to 09:45

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, cronexpression

I assumed that a cron expression that triggers every 5 minutes from 09:00 to 09:45 should be as simple as `0 0-45/5 9 * * ?`. However, using this as a `<cron-expression>` in a Quartz.NET XML configuration file produces this error:

```
The value '0 0-45/5 9 * * ?' is invalid according to its datatype
```

My `<trigger>` is of the type `<cron>`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The full XML configuration of the trigger is as follows:

```
<trigger>
  <cron>
    <name>HealthCheckJobTrigger2</name>
    <group>G</group>
    <description>Run the job from 9:00 to 9:45 every 5 minutes</description>
    <job-name>HealthCheckJob</job-name>
    <job-group>G</job-group>
    <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
    <cron-expression>0 0-45/5 9 * * ?</cron-expression>
  </cron>
</trigger>
```

Comment: can you post the xml for the trigger?

Comment: @CircularReference Thank you for your interest in my question. I have added the trigger XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not make sense to specify a set of numbers at intervals. Instead, you should use this:

0 0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45 9 * * ?